# GtkComboBox invoking a warning about get_active_iter?

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, pygtk

I have a GtkComboBox's `changed` signal connected to the following function:

```
def changeCombo(self, widget):
  selected = self.ui['comboBox'].get_active_iter()
  ...
```

This sort-of-works. However, when the combo's associated model -- a ListStore -- is emptied (and rebuilt), I get this error when the function is invoked:

```
AttributeError: 'gtk.TreeView' object has no attribute 'get_active_iter'
```

Thereafter, the code destabilises and stops working properly. (If you select a valid entry, before getting this warning, it works fine.)

What's going on here? I realise the combobox is probably implemented as a TreeView by GTK, but `get_active_iter` is definitely a member of [ComboBox](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcombobox.html#method-gtkcombobox--get-active-iter)... Does this error imply that the availability of this function is contingent on the model containing items? The documentation, however, implies that a combobox without a selection (or an empty model) should return `None` for `get_active_iter`.

Comment: This looks unlikely -- ComboBox uses a Treeview internally but it is not a TreeView itself. Are you 100% sure you don't mis-set self.ui['comboBox'] to point to a treeview at some point?

Comment: Just checked -- to convince myself -- and, no: I have not accidentally pointed `self.ui['comboBox']` to something else. Also, the code works fine until the bug is manifested, which seems to occur when I run `clear` against the model that is assigned to the combobox.

Comment: FWIW: When I open the Glade file that defines this interface, the combobox doesn't show up in the designer unless you click it in the object tree. I don't see anything wrong with the XML -- and I tried tweaking the combobox in Glade to force a change -- but *maybe* that's an avenue for investigation...